# Tabbed page load only the selected page rather than as a whole

Tags: xamarin

So I have a tabbedpage with 5 pages, Now when I navigate to the page where there is  the tabbed page it loads all of the 5 pages that's why it's loading for so long. Is there a way to load only the open page rather than loading all of them

Comment: Per the Xamarin docs: `The TabbedPage does not support UI virtualization. Therefore, performance may be affected if the TabbedPage contains too many child elements.` So it really depends upon how you are constructing your pages and if you are using page swiping and off screen caching (on Android it is using a native ViewPager)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Per the Xamarin docs: The TabbedPage does not support UI
>   virtualization. Therefore, performance may be affected if the
>   TabbedPage contains too many child elements. So it really depends upon
>   how you are constructing your pages and if you are using page swiping
>   and off screen caching (on Android it is using a native ViewPager)